# Using Android's <merge> XML element on rootview for activity's layout

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-lint

I am using the following layout:

```
---------------------
FrameLayout
    .>>. FrameLayout
    .>>. FrameLayout
---------------------
```

This layout is set on some `Activity` using `setContentView()`.
I just run lint to analyse my project and got the following message:

```
MergeRootFrame: FrameLayout can be replaced with <merge> tag
```

I understand and use the merge element in certain layouts but I fail to understand how can I be advised to merge the root element in my layout when there is no obvious parent to merge with, when I do the correction and run it all goes well but for some reason this feels a bit fishy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the following post by Romain Guy:
http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/03/01/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-part-1/

`"the parent of an activity’s content view is always a FrameLayout"`

Answered my question q:)

Answer (score 1):

The window provided for your application by the system has a FrameLayout that is the parent for your Activity's view hierarchy.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? or are you just stating a fact by looking at HierarchyViewer or something?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's documented anywhere, but I've only ever seen a FrameLayout as the parent view of an Activity's view hierarchy.